# JavaFX: Creating a board grid with Permanin twist

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a board game (first ported to JavaFX) in which the player must kill the opponent's piece going through a loop.

[image: CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=138535, Permanin game board]

The above is provided on the Wikipedia page for Surakurta (another name for Permanin). But, I have been only able to build a grid of this sort:

[image: JavaFX Permanin app by Silcos (SHUKANT PAL)]

How can I create those roundabouts in the corners?

Implementation details for already built grid: GridPane filled with 36 `BoardInput extends javafx.scene.control.Button` objects. These objects are special because they automatically create a `Background` with three `BackgroundFill` objects - horizontal line, vertical line, and the pebble circular fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Path`. `ArcTo` elements allow you to create the circular parts. `HLineTo`, `VLineTo` and `ClosePath` can be used for the straight sections:

Furthermore I don't recommend using `BackgroundFill`s. I'd prefer overlaying invisible buttons on top of the board visuals or handling `MouseEvent`s for the `GridPane` itself.

#### Example

```
private static ArcTo createArc(double radius, double dx, double dy) {
    ArcTo result = new ArcTo(radius, radius, 0, dx, dy, true, true);
    result.setAbsolute(false);
    return result;
}

private static HLineTo createHLine(double length) {
    HLineTo result = new HLineTo(length);
    result.setAbsolute(false);
    return result;
}

private static VLineTo createVLine(double length) {
    VLineTo result = new VLineTo(length);
    result.setAbsolute(false);
    return result;
}

private static Path createPath(double radius, double midSize, Color storke) {
    final double lineLength = 2 * radius + midSize;

    Path result = new Path(
            new MoveTo(radius, 2 * radius), // start at left end of top horizontal line
            createArc(radius, radius, -radius), // top left loop
            createVLine(lineLength), // down
            createArc(radius, -radius, -radius), // bottom left loop
            createHLine(lineLength), // right
            createArc(radius, -radius, radius), // bottom right loop
            createVLine(-lineLength), // up
            createArc(radius, radius, radius),
            new ClosePath() // left
    );
    result.setStroke(storke);
    result.setStrokeWidth(10);
    return result;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(
            createPath(100, 50, Color.GREEN),
            createPath(50, 150, Color.AQUA)
    ));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**Output**

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: You have used a stackpane. Where should I add the 'Path' objects in a GridPane (or any cell)?

Comment: You could add the paths as nodes spanning all rows and columns with a center alignment, but I'd recommend using a `Pane` and determining the positions of all elements (the `Circle`s, the yellow `Rectangle`) yourself That way you don't need to rely on the layout algorithm of some layout. Doing this shouldn't be too hard since every piece on the board is placed on some "grid" and all path segments start and end on intersections of this "grid": Just use the inner square of the green line as size.

Comment: Could you help me with how to calculate the button positions on top of the grid? I need to know where to place the buttons after getting this right. I have already added the `Pane` and positioned the paths.